# Send the recorded data into another grid in extjs

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs

```html
Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
 init: function() {
  this.control({
    'userlist': {
                 render: function() {
                  console.log('inside render event');
                 },
                 itemdblclick: this.onDbClickonGridRow
  
             },
             'newTable': {
                 render: function() {
                  console.log('inside table event');
                 },
                 // itemdblclick: this.onDbClickonGridRow
  
             }
  })
 },
 onDbClickonGridRow: function(event, e, eOpts) {
  console.log(e.data);
  var uForm = Ext.create('widget.newTable');
  console.log(uForm);
  uForm.loadRecord(e);//error here
 }
});

This is my controller of the application
```

```html
Ext.define('AM.view.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',
    title: 'All Users',
    initComponent: function() {
     this.title= 'Modified title';
        this.store = {
            fields: ['name', 'email'],
            data  : [
                {name: 'avi',    email: 'avi@gmail.com'},
                {name: 'abhi', email: 'abhi@gmail.com'},{name: 'Nikhil',    email: 'n@gmail.com'},
                {name: 'manu', email: 'manu@gmail.com'}

            ]
        };

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});


This is userList.js
```

This is the original panel from which i would like to send my data on double clicking the rows of the table to the newTable.js

```js
var newTable=Ext.define('AM.view.newTable' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.newTable',
    title: 'All Users',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.title= 'New title';
        this.store = {
            fields: ['name', 'email'],
        };

        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1}
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

This is an newTable.js into which i would like to insert my data into.

The problem here is that i am able to collect the data through e.data ,but the no idea how i can post it into the newTable.js from uform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Store of the grid using `getStore()` and the add the record to it using `add()`.

```
uForm.getStore().add(e);
```